Two different snap to Grid area in a PCB
I one of my projcts I faced with an PCB that there are two regions with different snap to grip values (software Altium Designer):

Why would we need this in a PCB? How should I make it or remove it?

We don't know why your project would needs two snap areas and we don't know what program you are using to give you a menu to adjust grid snap settings. Could you add details?

@ Justme The software is Altium Desinger

This is opinion based. Isn't that a close?             You don't /need/ more than one grid, but it might be very practical if you're placing components that typically fit on different grids.

@ MrGerber do you know how we can make it?

@Andromeda do not put a space after the @

How should I make it or remove it? You paid very good money for Altium Designer. Read the documentation, and if you can't find it there, contact their support. You pay for that stuff!
